# Pytorch CrossEntropyLoss Tensorflow Equivalent

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I am currently translating a pytorch code into tensorflow.
There is a point that i am aggregating 3 losses in a tensorflow custom loop and i get an error that i am passing a two dimensional array vs a 1 dimensional into CategoricalCrossEntropy of tensorflow which is very legit and i understand why this happens... but in the pytorch code i am passing the same shapes and it's perfectly working with CrossEntropyLoss. Does anybody know what i have to do to transfer this into TF?
the shapes that are passing in are (17000,100) vs (17000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the loss `loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer, already tried that out but it doesn't work.. there is a minor squeeze that has to happen because sparse categorical crossentropy is expecting (1, 17000) for the second array but when i do that i get a division by zero error.

Comment: It rather expected `(17000,)` shape. Then I suggest you include more details in your post.